# How to convert Tuples to Map with Set in Scala

Tags: scala

This is my first post.
I would like to convert Tuples to Map with Set in Scala as shown below.

```
Set((1,"a"),(2,"b"),(1,"c"))
```

↓

```
Map(1 -> Set("a","c"), 2 -> Set("b"))
```

Is there any way to make it simpler?

If there is any missing information, please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to check all methods in Scala collection library, it's pretty extensive and usually covers all the common cases like this one.

Here is how you do it:

```
Set((1,"a"),(2,"b"),(1,"c"))
  .groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

result:

```
res0: Map[Int,Set[String]] = Map(2 -> Set(b), 1 -> Set(a, c))
```

**UPD**: As @OlegPyzhcov pointed out, `mapValues` creates a lazy view of the original map, where values are reevaluated on every access. This may be inefficient if map is repeatedly accessed after the creation. To solve that problem you may want to materialize map in the end. I think the simplest way to do that is following:

```
.mapValues(_.map(_._2)).map(identity)
```

@OlegPyzhcov please correct me if there is a simpler/more efficient way.

Comment: Note that `mapValues` is lazy so it will create a new set on every element access, printing, etc.

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov thanks for pointing this out. You never stop learning :)

Comment: This is particularly important to know if the map is serialized (Spark users know that!). Unmaterialized maps (when you call mapValues) are not serializable in Scala (2.10 & 2.11 at least) and your Spark job may fail, whereas if you materialize them, all is fine.